# Find top 3 most ordered categories from X country; and the city with most orders from 2nd category from that country

Tags: sql, sql-server

So as the title says, I need to find three categories with the most highest numbers of orders in France and also the city for the second category that has the most orders. 
I was able to achieve this, but I think there might be a better approach to solving this.

Firstly, I found the three categories. And for the second part (for the city) I had to modify the first query by obtaining the second category from it to adjust it for the second (if i make any sense).
I don't see this as a good approach whatsoever; I want one query for both parts, if it is possible to do so. 
I also tried with cte function and numbering the rows to fetch them later, but failed too. I'm not really aware of all the functions available in mssql, beginner here. 
From programming perspective I see this as achievable, not sure if it can be done here too. Any thoughts on the matter would be much appreciated.

```
--1. find top 3 categories with most orders in France
        create view top3infrance as
        select top 3 c.CategoryName, o.ShipCountry, count(o.OrderID) as total
        from Categories as c
        left join Products as p on c.CategoryID = p.CategoryID
        left join [Order Details] as od on p.ProductID = od.ProductID
        left join Orders as o on od.OrderID = o.OrderID
            where o.ShipCountry in ('france')
        group by c.CategoryName, o.ShipCountry
        order by total desc

    --2. city with most orders from second category from the above query

        create view top1infrance as 
        select top 1 sub.ShipCountry, sub.ShipCity,sub.CategoryName, sub.total
        from 
        (select top 3 c.CategoryName, o.ShipCountry, o.ShipCity, count(o.OrderID) as total
        from Categories as c
        left join Products as p on c.CategoryID = p.CategoryID
        left join [Order Details] as od on p.ProductID = od.ProductID
        left join Orders as o on od.OrderID = o.OrderID
            where o.ShipCountry in ('france') and c.CategoryName in('seafood')
        group by c.CategoryName, o.ShipCountry, o.ShipCity) as sub
        order by total desc

        select * from top3infrance
        select * from top1infrance
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  As I read this question, it looks like two questions -- which makes it too broad.

Comment: Can you please provide some result set that tells us what you are trying to achieve?